# Problema ao usar ApplicationScope JSF

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2.2

Estou com um problema ao usar o [`ApplicationScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/bean/ApplicationScoped.html) no JSF para guardar minha lista de países.

Fiz este managedBean:

```java
package view.point;

import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

import view.country.CountryHelper;
import model.country.Country;

@ManagedBean(eager = true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class ApplicationScope {

    private Country country = CountryHelper.findAll().get(1);

    public ApplicationScope() {
    }

    public Country getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(Country country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

}
```

Bom, até ai tudo bem, debuguei e o valor está chegando certinho. O real problema é para pegar este valor.

Tentei pegar através do **ExternalContext** e sempre que executo esse código:

```java
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getApplicationMap().get("country");
```

eu tenho como valor **NULL**. Alguém sabe o por que? Estou fazendo algo errado?

Bom, obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, acabei conseguindo resolver. Vou postar o código final:

Bean da ApplicationScope:

```
package view.point;
import javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;

import view.country.CountryHelper;
import model.country.Country;


@ManagedBean(eager = true, name = "pauloMB")
@ApplicationScoped

public class ApplicationScope {

private Country country = CountryHelper.findAll().get(1);

public ApplicationScope() {
}

public Country getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(Country country) {
    this.country = country;
}
}
```

E no meu outro bean, onde desejo acessar o valor, criei um objeto do meu managedbean de aplicação e injetei ele:

```
@ManagedProperty("#{pauloMB}")
private ApplicationScope applicationScope;
```

**OBS**: Coloquei um alias chamado pauloMB só para teste. Usando o mesmo nome da classe eu não consegui fazer, por algum motivo bizarro ele da erro.

E aqui eu pego o valor que eu quero:

```
@PostConstruct
public void initCountry() {
    System.out.println(applicationScope.getCountry());
}
```

Obrigado a todos, abraços.